# Scala - Which is the most efficient way to get the names of the null columns from spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, dataframe, null

I have a df like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   user_id|     apple|    orange|    banana|      pear|     table|      desk|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|         1|        13|      null|        55|      null|      null|      null|
|         2|        30|      null|      null|      null|      null|      null|
|         3|      null|      null|        50|      null|      null|      null|
|         4|         1|      null|         3|      null|      null|      null|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I would like to get back an Array[String] which contains the fruit column names which are have only null values. I would like to do this on a very big data frame so i don't want to sum the columns, i need a faster and much more efficient way. I need a Scala code.

So i need this list:

```
List(orange,pear)
```

I have this solution now, summing columns, but i need a solution without summing all of the columns:

```
val fruitList:  Array[String] = here are the fruit names 
val nullFruits: Array[String] = fruitList.filter(col => dataFrame.agg(sum(col)).first.get(0) == null)
```

Comment: Have you already tried something? Can you share your code, if any?

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov i edited my questin

Comment: Here is a solution without summing: `fruitList.filter(f => df.filter(col(f).isNotNull).isEmpty)`

Comment: @jrook I can't use isEmpty here

Comment: @ash Can you use `.count == 0`  instead? How about? `.rdd.isEmpty` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using Spark's `describe` too:

```
val r1  = df.select(fruitList.head, fruitList.tail :_*)
  .summary("count")

//alternatively

val r1 = df.select(fruitList.head, fruitList.tail :_*)
   .describe()
   .filter($"summary" === "count")

+-------+-----+------+------+----+
|summary|apple|orange|banana|pear|
+-------+-----+------+------+----+
|  count|    3|     0|     3|   0|
+-------+-----+------+------+----+
```

And to extract the desired values:

```
r1.columns.tail
  .map(c => (c,r1.select(c).head.getString(0) == "0"))
  .filter(_._2 == true)
  .map(_._1)
```

which gives:

```
Array(orange, pear)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this describe calculates a lots of thing, if I have a huge data frame maybe it is not the most effective solution, or am I wrong?

Comment: I have a run a small performance test (Spark local mode, 2 Mio lines of data). The describe way takes only half the time than using a reduce function.

Comment: @ash the only way to make sure is to run tests. Anyways, I edited the answer to use `summary` instead which will only calculate `count` and nothing else.

Comment: @jrook i can not use the .summary() and the filter($"summary" === "count"), but why?

Comment: @ash what spark version are you using and what error you are getting? You can try `filter(col("summary") === "count")` too and see if it works.

Comment: @jrook Spark 2.1.0  and Scala 2.11.8, yes this version works but the summary() does not

Comment: @ash I can't find summary() in spark 2.1.0 [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) either. Have you tried `describe` and compared it with other methods?